# Why is "random" in the definition of discrete random variable?

Tags: statistics, soft-question

We defined discrete random variable as follows:

Suppose $S$ is a countable sample space. Then a function $X:S\to R$ is called a discrete random variable.

The lecturer made a note that the "random" part of the name has nothing to do with predictability, so I ask - What is the motivation for putting "random" in the name?

Comment: Because $S$ is associated with a probability distribution and they form a probability space. The function $X$ itself is not random at all, but its inputs are. Therefore the output values are random as well.

Comment: Yes, you will pick an element $s\in S$ at random, and then calculate $X(s)$ to get a "random value."

Comment: IMO your instructor's comment is putting the proverbial cart before the horse -- predictability is a feature of randomness, not vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit strange that he would say "random" has nothing to do with probability.

Here's a typical example.  Say you throw two dice and $X$ is the sum of the two numbers you get. Then $X$ is a random variable whose value is in the set $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ Then the sample space is the set
$$
S= \left\{ \begin{array}{cccccc}
(1,1), & (1,2), & (1,3), & (1,4), & (1,5), & (1,6) \\
(2,1), & (2,2), & (2,3), & (2,4), & (2,5), & (2,6) \\
(3,1), & (3,2), & (3,3), & (3,4), & (3,5), & (3,6) \\
(4,1), & (4,2), & (4,3), & (4,4), & (4,5), & (4,6) \\
(5,1), & (5,2), & (5,3), & (5,4), & (5,5), & (5,6) \\
(6,1), & (6,2), & (6,3), & (6,4), & (6,5), & (6,6)
\end{array} \right\}.
$$

If you pick one of the $36$ outcomes at random, then $X\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ is also random.